# Change background and foreground color using x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, qemu

I am trying to change the background and foreground color of the screen using x86 assembly but its not working:

```
mov ax,0
mov al,11101100b
int 10h
ret
```

As far as I know, the code is correct. Am I doing something wrong? I previously tried this code:

```
mov ax, 0600h
mov bh, 11110000b
mov cx, 0000h
mov dx, 1010h
int 10h
```

but it made a small white rectangle on the corner of the screen and covered some text.

Comment: What operating system etc ? Is this 16 bit DOS or something ?

Comment: `int 10h, ah=0` is used to set the video mode. I don't know why you think it sets foreground/background colors.

Comment: @PaulR: I am running the code via QEMU.

Comment: @interjay: I followed the method mentioned here: http://arbitcode.blogspot.in/2012/02/setting-background-in-assembly-8086.html

Comment: @theblixguy The example on the page you linked is pretty well documented and describes exactly what each line is doing. The code you tried in the first example is significantly different from that code. Are you sure you know what you're doing?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: That was the code I first wrote but it didn't work so i realized I must be doing something wrong, then I visited that link and the code works but the rectangle appears on top of the text that is printed and I do not want that.

Comment: @theblixguy I was referring to your first code sample which uses `ah=0` and which isn't in that blog post. I suggest you read some documentation, such as [here](http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~ray/teaching/CA296/notes/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.html).

Answer (score 1):

The code you tried first from [ArbitCode](http://arbitcode.blogspot.pt/2012/02/setting-background-in-assembly-8086.html), works perfectly and it's very well documented.

> ...the rectangle appears on top of the text...

This is probably because you didn't set the correct window size. By default the video mode is set to mode 3, which is 80x25.

Just to make sure, set it yourself by doing:

```
MOV AH,00h      ; Set video mode
MOV AL,03h      ; Mode 3 (Color text)
INT 10H
```

I made some changes to the code that you used before and I'll try to explain them:

```
MOV AX, 0600h        ; AH=06(scroll up window), AL=00(entire window)
MOV BH, 00010111b    ; left nibble for background (blue), right nibble for foreground (light gray)
MOV CX, 0000h        ; CH=00(top), CL=00(left)
MOV DX, 1010h        ; DH=19(bottom), DL=50(right)
INT 10h
```

As you can see above, DH and DL define the bottom right corner. Our window size is 80x25, so we must set DH to 19h (25 in decimal) and DL to 50h (80 in decimal).

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather vague. Are you trying to paint the whole screen with a single color?

Interrupt 10 doesn't have a concept of a current color/background of the screen. It's capable of outputting a single character with a provided background and color (function AH=9); if you use it in a loop by screen row and column, you can fill the whole screen with a color.

For the record, in text mode it's much easier to read/write the framebuffer directly (at 0xb800:0000) than using interrupt 10h.

Comment: Yes! I want the entire screen to be blue and text in white.

Comment: Well then, swipe the whole screen with the space character and attribute byte 17H. Need I spell out the whole loop?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how I can do that.

Comment: Are you really sure assembly is the right language for this project? You don't code in assembly unless you absolutely have to; this isn't one of those cases. Or is this a class assignment?

Comment: I just like to comment on this. This isn't a place for school kids to let others do the code. Research and try it yourself, ask if you need help but don't bother to ask the whole code.